# Draw pixels buffers with OpenGL Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, java-native-interface, pixel

I have a byte Buffer array

```
static IntBuffer byteBuffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(8300000);
```

I put a lot of pixels on it like following :

```
 byteBuffer.put(256) // ALPHA
 byteBuffer.put(150) // RED
 byteBuffer.put(152) // GREEN
 byteBuffer.put(23) // BLUE
 byteBuffer.put(152) // ALPHA
 ... etc etc
```

In my Render class that implements `GLSurfaceView.Renderer`, I have this 3 methods overrided :

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glTexImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, 1920, 1080, 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, SocketActivity.byteBuffer);
}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    init(width, height);
}

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

}
```

I want to rendera big texture on 1920x1080 resolution that's why I allocated 8300000 (1920*1080*4).

But it does not display anything.

Comment: `glTexImage2D` loads the texture, it doesn't draw it.

Comment: Then how to draw after I loaded it ?

Comment: [Start by learning OpenGL ES](http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-one-getting-started/)

Comment: Could you just tell me the function that I should use please. I saw many tutorials, many things on OpenGL but never found something for my purpose. I even don't know if that I'm doing is correct or no as I have no display at all...

Comment: There is no "one function". To draw that texture you'd need to load the texture, setup a vertex and fragment shader, create a vertex buffer for a fullscreen quad and a create vertex arrays. Then you'd go about binding it all and issue a draw call.

Comment: Ook thank you, this informs me a lot about how OpenGL works.
Can you provide me a sample with my purpose ? I added these lines :
gl.glGenTextures(1, vertexes, 0);            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, vertexes[0]);            gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
gl.glTexImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, 1920, 1080, 0, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, SocketActivity.byteBuffer);

Comment: I gave you a link to learn OpenGL ES, which is already against Stack Overflow's rules. This website isn't about teaching or writing samples.

Comment: Vallentin's link would get you started great. You use a fragment and vertex shader and then you need vertex and index buffers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved ! Here is the order for anyone who wanna do it.

In `init` function :

```
glViewport(GL_ZERO, GL_ZERO, width, height);
glGenTextures(1, &idTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, idTexture);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, idTexture);
glUseProgram(gProgram);
```

In `draw` function :

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_ZERO, GL_RGB, width, height, GL_ZERO, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glVertexAttribPointer(position, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat), vertices);
glVertexAttribPointer(inputTextureCoordinate, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat), vVertices);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(gvPositionHandle);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(inputTextureCoordinate);
glUniform1i(baseMapLoc, GL_ZERO);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices);
```

You see the idea. Thank you very much to all those who enlightened me.